# Временно оставлять переменные

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день! Имею несколько UITextField для регистрации, и кнопку информаци "о программе"

Информация "о программе" открывается на новом ViewController (так надо) и после с нее возвращаемся назад к форме регистрации, но при этом все поля, которые были заполнены ранее, становятся чистыми.

Как при возвращении на окно регистрации оставить все данные, которые пользователь заполнил, в своих полях

Comment: Опиши как ты переходишь на "о программе". Как по мне, лишняя модель с стронг пропертями для регистрации будет держать память(могу ошибаться). Я бы в контроллере регистрации добавил проперти, в которые сохранял введенные стринги, и во время viewdidappear подставлял их в поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите модельный объект - наследник NSObject который будет содержать все поля данные которых Вам необходимы:

```
@interface  RegistrationDataModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;

@end
```

После этого в зависимости от варианта навигации между двумя ViewController'ами либо присваивайте этот объект соответствующей проперти ViewController'а либо передавайте делегированием с одного на другой. После нажатия кнопки сохранить переписывайте данные с модельного объекта в базу данных.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, сейчас запидалькаю